# Dashed Line in Border Matrix

Tags: bordermatrix, addlines

How can I create a bordermatrix with dashed lines as the picture shows? I tried to use array, but can’t get the exactly same thing. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\(\begin{bNiceArray}[first-row, first-col]{cc}[margin, cell-space-limits = 3.5pt]
  & A & B \\
A & \Block[borders={bottom, tikz=densely dashed}]{1-2}{}
    \Block[borders={right, tikz=densely dashed}]{2-1}{} 
    A & B \\
B & C & D \\
\end{bNiceArray}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the package `nicematrix`, you can define commands and letters for a custom style of line (with characteristics defined by Tikz).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       command = dashedline ,
       tikz = densely dashed ,
       total-width = \pgflinewidth % optional 
     }
  }

\(\begin{bNiceArray}[first-row, first-col]{cIc}[margin, cell-space-limits = 3.5pt]
  & A & B \\
A & A & B \\
\dashedline
B & C & D \\
\end{bNiceArray}\)

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]